# django, how to Use Count in Q

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Group(models.Model):

    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Member(models.Model):

    group = models.ForeignKey('Group')
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    gender = models.BooleanField() #False is "female", True is "male"
```

How can I find a `Group` who has no `Member`, or where the number of male  `Member`s is zero?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
Group.objects.filter( Q(member__isnull=True) |
                      Q(member__isnull=False) &
                      Q( Count(member__gender=True)=0 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution,

```
Group.objects.filter(Q(member__isnull=True) | ~Q(member__gender=True))
```

When you're trying to fetch something that might return multiple results, you should use *filter* and not *get*

If you want to count the query set, you can use,

```
Group.objects.filter(Q(member__gender=False )).count()
```

Comment: Yeah, filter is right, but your solutions not work. I want find "Group" who has no Members or all of its Members is Female.

Comment: (1) Group.objects.filter(Q(member__isnull=True) | ~Q(member__gender=True)).distinct(),   you should add distinct.
(2) Your solution is half right, because it is not robust. what if I want "male  Members is 2".
(3) But it work anyway, so mark your answer useful.